# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR Split URL

Tags: regex, oracle, substring

I haven't been working much with regular expressions, however, I am wanting to break up a URL into the different parts of a URL: namely SCHEME (http or https), IP_ADRESS (1.1.1.1 OR a hostname such as dummy.org), PORT (it can really be any length) and then finally the CONTEXT

As you can see below, this is what I've managed to achieve so far, probably not the best way :). However, my only struggle at the moment is I've catered for if the IP address is a number, but want to also cater incase it's a hostname. How do you cater for anything between the second / and the first : ?
And then lastly I am also having a tough time with the context, I can't seem to get the second part. I need any value from the third / until the end

```
*SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '^https?*') AS "SCHEME",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\') AS "IP_ADDRESS",
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '[0-9]+\.*/'),'[/]', '') AS "PORT",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '^https?://[^/]+(.*/)[^/].*', 1, 1, null, 1) AS "CONTEXT"
from (
     select 'https://1.2.3.4:80801/test/test2' as url from dual
    );*
```

| SCHEME | IP_ADDRESS | PORT | CONTEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https | 1.2.3.4 | 80801 | /test/ |

Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a lot simpler? The scheme always ends in `://`, the IP address (with optional port) ends at the next `/`, and if the port is present, it starts at a colon between the `://` ending the scheme and the next `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT url,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '^([^:]*)://',1,1,null,1) AS "SCHEME",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '^([^:]*://)?([^/:]+)(:|/|$)',1,1,null,2) AS "HOST",
    REGEXP_substr(url, '^([^:]*://)?([^/:]+):(\d+)',1,1,null,3) AS "PORT",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(url, '^([^:]*://)?([^/]+)(/.*)?', 1, 1, null, 3) AS "CONTEXT"
from (
     select 'https://1.2.3.4:80801/test/test2' as url from dual
     union all select 'https://example.com:80801/test/test2' as url from dual
     union all select 'https://example.com/test/test2' as url from dual
     union all select 'http://example.com:8080/test/test2' as url from dual
     union all select 'http://example.com/' as url from dual
     union all select 'http://example.com' as url from dual
     union all select 'http://example.com:888' as url from dual
     union all select 'http://www.example.com' as url from dual
     union all select 'ftp://example.com/test/test2' as url from dual
     union all select 'skype://username' as url from dual
    );
```

Result:

```
URL                                  SCHEME HOST                 PORT     CONTEXT
------------------------------------ ------ -------------------- -------- --------------------
https://1.2.3.4:80801/test/test2     https  1.2.3.4              80801    /test/test2
https://example.com:80801/test/test2 https  example.com          80801    /test/test2
https://example.com/test/test2       https  example.com                   /test/test2
http://example.com:8080/test/test2   http   example.com          8080     /test/test2
http://example.com/                  http   example.com                   /
http://example.com                   http   example.com
http://example.com:888               http   example.com          888
http://www.example.com               http   www.example.com
ftp://example.com/test/test2         ftp    example.com                   /test/test2
skype://username                     skype  username
```